# How to override onSetContentView while Using Ratio Resolution policy in Andengine Base game activity

Tags: andengine

I am developing (Learning to build :)  ) a game with  andengine GLES2.
I am using base game acitvity , and i overrides the setContent view to place my admob ad.
Every thing works fine except the resolution policy .
 **Ratio Resolution policy** is the one I am using along with **CAMERA_WIDTH = 800; and CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;**

The issue is whenever overided onsetContentView **scene is not get aligned to center** ,**margins displayed only on bottom** not on both top and bottom, Same will cause when horizontally align the margin will be displayed only at right side, not on both sides. how can i correct this. I am giving my code below

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    System.out.println("Content setting");
    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);


    final LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT ;

    final android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            layoutParams);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT
                    );

    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);

    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);
    frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);


    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);

}
```

here is the image what i get you can see the white margin below the scene if you select the image ( its not get into attention due to stack overflow also had white background )

[image]

any suggestions will be very help full to me

How Can i solve this Isuue Please help me

Thanks to all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED:

After a little big game with the layouts I am able to fix this.

Now my surface view get aligned to center and the ad displays in a desired way.

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {

    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);


    final android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
    surfaceViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    relativeLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);


    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxx");
    adView.refreshDrawableState();
    frameLayout.addView(adView);
    relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout);

    this.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutLayoutParams);



}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. you just saved me quite a lot of time fiddling around with the layouts;) Although my ad was supposed to be at the bottom.. now it's on the top – do you have any idea why this could be?